# Javascript - Uncaught Type Error: undefined is not a function - JQuery vertical navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this jquery bit of code into my .js file

```
$(function () {
        // Vertical tabs configuration
        $("#myVerticalTabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
        $("#myVerticalTabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
    })
```

this code is supposed to add a vertical navbar in my app. I followed this tutoriel : http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical and tried to apply it in my asp.net MVC application. I have put the code into a javascript file which referenced into a view in my app.
This is the code of the div that is supposed to be displayed as a vertical navbar :

```
<div id="myVerticalTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-vertical-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-vertical-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-vertical-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-vertical-1">
        <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
        <p>Content1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-vertical-2">
        <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
        <p>Content2.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-vertical-3">
        <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
        <p>Content3.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
The script is referenced into a .cshtml page (in the bottom of the page):

```
<!-- Begin Global Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Application/GlobalJS/globalScript.js"></script>
    <!-- End Global Scripts -->
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check whether you have included jquery js file **before** jquery.ui js file. If ok, check whether you are including JQuery more than once.

Comment: What is not happening, Can you create a jsfiddle for your code.

Comment: @Sandeeproop I have put the link for the tutoriel, it is supposed to display a vertical navbar, the navbar is not displayed and javascript throws an error.

Comment: @Deepal I am including jquery only once. I am using JQuery all along my app, this is the first that I have this kind of errors.

Comment: Check whether you have included jquery js file **before** jquery.ui js file. That order is important because Jquery UI needs jquery to be included before.

Comment: Have you included jquery-ui.css and css displayed in tutorial into your code?